# Style jquery mobile to degrade

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

I've pretty much finished my first JQM web site and am going through my pages adding css so they still look good when javascript is disabled.
I've had a look through some of the JQM gallery sites and it looks like nobody else bothers....after trying to style a listview I can't say I'm surprised! :)

It's taken me a while to add basic styles that don't mess up the JQM enhanced version.

I'd like to know other people's thoughts on styling a JQM site to degrade.
Does anybody bother doing it?
Is it as difficult as I'm finding it or am I missing an easy method?

Any advice gratefully received!

Comment: Keep in mind that it doesn't make a lot of sense to try this if the site doesn't work with disabled JavaScript. If the site's functionality relies on JavaScript, then you should rather replace the gallery etc. with a notification, that the user should enable JavaScript.

Comment: The site is fully functional without javascript, I've just used JQM to enhance the look of it thinking it would be an easy task to go through at the end with js disabled and style the pages. Unfortunately it's not that easy!

Comment: The first thing I would do, is to compare the markup with and without enabled JavaScript and add the classes to the elements in the degraded version where possible. That way you should be able to reuse a lot of the jQuery Mobile style. But this is really tedious work, I wish you a lot of patience.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've done so far and you're absolutely spot on....it's VERY tedious work! Thanks for your thoughts maenu